# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll without explanation

Tags: c#, mysql

i tried to insert some data into my mysql database but i get this error with no other explanation:

'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll

```
try {

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(costanti.MySQLConnection);

        conn.Open();

        string comm = "INSERT INTO datilogin (Username, Password, Email) VALUES (@username, @psw, @email)";


        string user = txtUsername.Text;
        string pass = txtPassword.Text;
        string email = txtEmail.Text;

        Console.WriteLine(user + " " + pass + " " + email);


        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(comm, conn);
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@psw", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();

        this.Hide();
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Show();

    } catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException) {
        label6.Visible = true;
    }
```

the output is:

Thread 0x2bcc ended with code 0 (0x0).

Username not used - CONTINUE

Valid domain - CONTINUE

Email not used - CONTINUE

test test test@gmail.com

Exception generated: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll

The program '[7384] ciproviamo.exe' is terminated with code 0 (0x0)

Comment: Could you print the exception when catching it and share the output with us?

Comment: Can you share the entire stack trace for the error as it will make diagnosing it much easier.

Comment: Il thread 0x2bcc è terminato con il codice 0 (0x0).
Username non usato - CONTINUA
Dominio Valido - CONTINUA
Email non usata - CONTINUA
test test test@gmail.com
Eccezione generata: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
Il programma '[7384] ciproviamo.exe' è terminato con il codice 0 (0x0).

Comment: Enable logging : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

replace **cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()** with **cmd2.ExecuteScalar()**